# Magento 2: URL Rewrite not working through .htaccess

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, url-rewrite, 301-redirect

I want to redirect some old URL's to new URL's I'm doing it in my `.htaccess` path: `/root/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## Enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    Redirect 301 https://www.example.com/store/bra_bust_lift.html https://www.example.com/intimates/womens-intimates/bra-converters.html
```

after that when I hit old URL it redirect me to `404 Page`, it should redirect me to new URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and enable Web Server Rewrites

To enable URL rewrites

- **Stores**>**Configuration**> **Web**
- Expand the **Search Engine Optimization section**
- Set **Use Web Server Rewrites** to “Yes.”
- When
  complete, tap **Save Config**

Follow this link for more info https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-how-to-configure-url-rewrites/ .

Try to update your rule into this .

```
Redirect 301 /store/bra_bust_lift.html /intimates/womens-intimates/bra-converters.html
```

Check if you apache needs a restart .
Do a flush cache storage.

Check if you use nginx instead of apache .

Comment: Web Server Rewrites was enabled, actually the problem was with my server I'm using nginix I had to add urls to it.

Comment: Glad you fixed it

Comment: Please update your answer so I can approve it...

Comment: Updated @PartabSaifuddinZakir . Thank you